# Malformed record literal, but the so-called literal is data from a table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this query that returns a flat representation of a three-level hieararchy of clinics, doctors and available appointments:

```sql
select * from search_by_location(20,138.6,-34.9,null,0,0,1,99,current_date,7)
```

I'm trying to use it as a subquery to generate a proper three-level hierarchy:

```sql
with
a as (select * from search_by_location(20,138.6,-34.9,null,0,0,1,99,current_date,7)),
b as (
  select   business_name,
           address1,
           address2,
           suburb,
           postcode,
           state_acronym,
           phone_no,
           latitude,
           longitude,
           clinic_url_display_name,
           (first_name,
            preferred_name,
            last_name,
            gender,
            doctor_url_display_name,
            gravatar_md5,
            array_agg(appointment_start)
           )::doctor_appointments_row doctor
  from     a
  group by business_name,
           address1,
           address2,
           suburb,
           postcode,
           state_acronym,
           phone_no,
           latitude,
           longitude,
           clinic_url_display_name,
           first_name,
           preferred_name,
           last_name,
           gender,
           doctor_url_display_name,
           gravatar_md5
)
select   (business_name,
          (address1,
           address2,
           suburb,
           postcode,
           state_acronym
          )::address_row,
          phone_no,
          (latitude,
           longitude)::coords_row,
          clinic_url_display_name,
          array_agg(doctor)
         )::clinic_doctor_appointments_row clinic
from     b
group by business_name,
         address1,
         address2,
         suburb,
         postcode,
         state_acronym,
         phone_no,
         latitude,
         longitude,
         clinic_url_display_name
```

When I execute it, I get the following error message:

```
ERROR:  malformed record literal: "0811112222"
DETAIL:  Missing left parenthesis.
```

That's weird, because I'm not specifying that literal anywhere in the query. It's data from the base query, specifically the `phone_no` column. Any idea what is causing this error and how to resolve it?

**Update:**

This runs without error (just replacing the part of the query after the `with`s):

```sql
with
a as (select * from search_by_location(20,138.6,-34.9,null,0,0,1,99,current_date,7)),
b as (
  select   business_name,
           address1,
           address2,
           suburb,
           postcode,
           state_acronym,
           phone_no,
           latitude,
           longitude,
           clinic_url_display_name,
           (first_name,
            preferred_name,
            last_name,
            gender,
            doctor_url_display_name,
            gravatar_md5,
            array_agg(appointment_start)
           )::doctor_appointments_row doctor
  from     a
  group by business_name,
           address1,
           address2,
           suburb,
           postcode,
           state_acronym,
           phone_no,
           latitude,
           longitude,
           clinic_url_display_name,
           first_name,
           preferred_name,
           last_name,
           gender,
           doctor_url_display_name,
           gravatar_md5
)
select * from b
```

In this case, there's no nesting of `array_agg`, which I think may be buggy.

Comment: It looks fine (all braces are balanced), would need the table definitions and data to figure this out. You should try to execute parts of your query seperatly and  simplify them until you find out when the problem starts and goes away. I would start with just executing the CTE you called b.

Answer (score 0):

I am betting that you will get the same error when running your function and that your real problem is in the return type.  This is the only place I can spot where this is possible, unless there is more to the question than you are saying.

My thinking is you should try to run

```
 select * from search_by_location(20,138.6,-34.9,null,0,0,1,99,current_date,7)
```

first.  Make sure that works.  If it does, then....

Take a look closely at the context where you are running the other query.  My guess is it is running inside a function which is trying to cast to a record or something,

Comment: That query is already well established as working in production. The query in my question is a first attempt at eventually generating hierarchical JSON. If I replace the final part of the query (the part after the `with`s) with `select * from b` the query runs without error. I've taken a more direct approach with JSON and got it to work, but the error is still a mystery to me.

Comment: It sounds to me like your query as posted then is correct, and your real problem has to do with something else.  Were you trying to do json_agg(*) by any chance?  If so your problem is, I think, your call to json_agg, not your query.  If you want to use json_agg, my recommendation is:  `SELECT json_agg(b) from b`